# Is it possible to automate tasks within a Macro in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, process, macros, recording

I am relevantly new to Macro therefore would like to know if the following is possible;

See what it is, I've created a Macro that compares the data on sheet1 to the data on sheet2 and reports the whole line were a difference is found onto sheet3.  It then highlights the exact cell in which the difference takes place in Sheet3.  I'm using MS office excel 2007 version.

So I am happy with the macro I have so far as this fits my purpose nicely.  However I am now spending alot of time on seperating the data out from sheet 3 onto seperate sheets, so I was wondering if it is possible to record the steps I take so that when I have to do this next month the process is alot quicker.

I have played around with the record button within the developers tab but not really sure this will work as the data that appears as a difference each month would be different, so can you record the path you are doing even if the length of the data would in fluctuate?

Within worksheet 3 there is now over 4,000 lines and columns go up to Q.  What I have been doing so far but would love to make this quicker is as follows;

I add a filter to worksheet 3 and start on column A and do the same thing all the way to column Q.  I filter per colour on each column and manually cut and paste this data onto a seperate workbook all together.  (this doesnt have to be on different workbooks, It could easily just start showing the split using worksheet 4).

If anyone has any idea's as to how I could make this secound step of my monthly process faster then please add a comment as all help will be greatly received by myself.

Kind regards,
andrea

Comment: well, I tend to say - you can nearly solve anything with excel-macros ;) but this is somewhat a big task you are asking for and you do not provide any examples to start on (code; data-examples). My suggestion would be, that you reduce this problem first to a small example and try to get a solution for it - with vab you can create filters dynamically, you can extract the data dynamically, and you might be even able to solve this just with some advanced filtering. Think about asking this on stackoverflow, and provide a small practical example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `xlDown` to get to the bottom without specifying where that is but if you create your macro by recording you will have to adjust the code to incorporate it.